# Error while fetching data using FindAsync in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await

[image: Error message]

[image: Service registration]

[image: Method definition]

[image: Caller method]

I am getting this error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.%22) when I call findAsync to fetch data based on a Id from db. I tried many solution but error persist.
Here is my method definition.

```
    public async Task<T> GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var data =  await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        return data;
    }
```

I am calling it like this

```
    var dietPlan =  await _dietPlanRepositry.GetById(request.Id);
```

my db context service life time is Transient and repos are added as Transient

The screenshots of my code are attached

Comment: Please provide code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: You either have something that isn't awaited, and/or you have something structured in parallel with the same DbContext instance. You likely should have a compiler warning  that an async method is not awaited. Asynchronous is something that is well suited to scenarios where you benefit from offloading the work from the current responding/working thread. There is no benefit in defaulting to make *everything* async other than headaches tracking down issues like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject to you repository IServiceScopeFactory instead of DbContext.

And try to modify your GetById as follows:

```
public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
   using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
   using (var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>())
   {
        var data =  await dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        return data;
   }
}
```